# PHP Cron Manager Script stops page load

Tags: php, ssh, cron

I'm trying to make a script that schedules a cron job that sends e-mails on a specific date. I followed [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428) for making a php cron manager, and it loaded with no problem. But when I tried to make a SSH connection with the script just to see if it would raise any errors, the page stops loading where I place the code, no errors are shown and no error_log file is created anywhere, I really don't understand why the page stops loading.

```
$crontab = new Ssh2_crontab_manager('xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx', '22', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
```

I only expect it to connect and continue the page or that it at least give me an error that I can search for the solution

Nothing, just a page that's partially loaded and no error, it just stops there.

Comment: Where is it trying to make an SSH connection to? All the code is running on the same server, right? Do you not have SSH access to the server yourself? I have to say this is probably the worse method of maintaining a crontab I have ever seen

Comment: Yes, I have access to SSH server myself, and all the code is in the same server. The problem is that I need my own code to make and delete cron jobs without having to do all those tasks manually. I could let the script run every hour forever, but I wanted the script to be able to auto-schedule and auto-delete after completion

Comment: _"without having to do all those tasks manually"_  How long have you spent working on this guide? You know creating a cron job is literally a **single** line of code right? How are your scheduled emails generated? What are you using to send them? I have loads of projects which do a similar thing which all just run as daily cron jobs which check the database for who to send emails to on that day, generate the emails and sends. Cron is for recurring tasks, if you literally want to schedule your command to run just once in the future you should be using `at`

Comment: I want to schedule a job to send emails, but not to send them all at once, but split into certain amounts per hour, so I'm trying to set a cron job that creates an hourly job then deletes itself, and the hourly job sends a number of emails then stops, and deletes itself after there aren't any more e-mails to send. Sorry if it's kinda confusing

Comment: Are the email addresses you want to send to being retrieved from a database or elsewhere?

Comment: Exactly, from a database, I will have the script fetch a number of e-mails, send them and delete from the database, then run again until there aren't any more e-mails meant to be sent that day, then it deletes the cron job

Comment: Are you going to be using php for your script to query the database and send the emails?

Comment: Yes, I will be using PHP to query the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach above totally over complicates what you are trying to do. You have a php script you want to run at certain intervals throughout the day, sending a few emails each time to people in your database.

Obviously I have no idea what your database looks like, but here's a basic concept.

- Add a column to your email addresses database called sent with
  default value set to 0
- Write your php script and in your database query use `LIMIT = 10` or
  whatever to only retrieve a few email addresses each time it runs,
  use `WHERE sent = 0` to only retrieve email addresses you havent sent
  to yet
- Then `UPDATE` each row to `SET sent = 1` after the script has run to
  mark those users as having already been emailed. Include some conditional code so that if there are no more email
  addresses for that day `WHERE sent = 0` then script just exits.
- Create a cron job to run at your chosen interval which runs your php
  script and just leave it.

There is no need to delete the cron job, if there are no emails to send it will just run briefly and quit. The whole point of cron jobs is to automate repetitive tasks, you set once and forget. The filters are flexible enough to give you a lot of control over when they run.

For example `0 9-17/2 * * 1-5 php /path/to/script.php` would run a script every other hour between 0900 and 1700, Monday to Friday